# Multisite Redirection to new domains

Tags: multisite, redirect, htaccess, domain

I have a multisite website with 5 domains in WordPress which uses WordPress MU Domain Mapping plugin.

I want to redirect every subpage to new domain, but we will be still using the homepage, because it contains some links inside of it, so root, `wp-admin` and `wp-login`, should be still accessible and not redirected. How to set this up in `.htaccess` so WordPress will still function?

example of a domain:

```
oldone.com/ --> no redirection
oldone.com/wp-admin --> no redirection
oldone.com/wp-login --> no redirection
oldone.com/about --> newone.com/about
oldone1.com/about --> newone1.com/about
... etc ...
```

`.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

### oldone.com redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldone.com$ [NC]
#redirects domain.com to www.oldone.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://oldone.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldone.com\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(wp-login/?|$)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(wp-admin/?|$)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newone.com/$1 [R=301,L]
####
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding something like the following at the *top* of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldone\.com
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-login
RewriteRule . http://newone.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Make sure the browser cache is clear. Change to 301 (if that is the intention) only when you are sure it's working OK.

Repeat for any other `oldoneN.com` / `newoneN.com` combos, unless there is a pattern with the domain names?

Alternatively, if you *never* want to redirect `/wp-admin` or `/wp-login` etc for any domain then you could include an *exception* for these URL-paths. Although that would probably interfere with some of the other MU directives.